# Querying undirected edge objects in an undirected networkx graph

Tags: networkx

Given an undirected graph in networkx:

```
graph=Graph()
graph.add_edge(1,2)
graph.add_edge(2,3)
```

When querying the edgeset of this graph using the method `graph.edges()`,the result is returned as a tuple, i.e. a *directed* view of the edgeset. In the example above, `graph.edges()` returns:

> [**(1, 2)**, (2, 3)]

If I would query all edges incident to vertex 2 (`graph.edges(2)`) I get a different directed view:

> [**(2, 1)**, (2, 3)]

This behavior is problematic if I have for instance an external dict that maps an edge (key) to some other object. For instance:

```
lookup={edge : some_object(edge) for edge in graph.edges()}
for edge in graph.edges(2):
  print(lookup(edge)) #throws key not found exception
```

The exception is thrown because key (1,2) exists, but (2,1) does not. What would be the best (efficient/pythonic/...) way to get an undirected object when iterating over an undirected graph in networkx? I could associate some_object(edge) with an edge as one of its attributes, but that doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: If you're using networkx v2.x, it might be worth looking at "ordered graphs": https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/ordered.html  These are basically graphs, but seem to avoid the problem you're having.  An alternative might be to always use `sorted(edge)` though that returns a list so you may want `tuple(sorted(edge))`.

Comment: Another option would be a `try.. except`.

Answer (score 0):

**dfs_labeled_edges(G, source)**  Traverses through the graph using depth first search.
Since dfs_edges stops after reaching every node, it will not always detect every edge.  Instead, dfs_labeled_edges can be implemented to obtain all the edge objects in an undirected graph.

Code:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx import dfs_labeled_edges

nodes = [1,2,3]
edges = [(1,2), (2,3)]
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)

undirectedGraphEdges = []

dfs = list(dfs_labeled_edges(G,1))

for edge in dfs:
    if(edge[:2] not in undirectedGraphEdges):
    undirectedGraphEdges.append(edge[:2])

if undirectedGraphEdges[0] not in edges:
    del undirectedGraphEdges[0]


print(undirectedGraphEdges)

# [(1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2)]
```